# Search of user's contacts: highlight part of the name that matches with the search, when using Data Binding and LongListSelector (WP8)

Tags: windows-phone-8, data-binding, highlight, longlistselector

I'm binding the user's contact list to a LongListSelector, as I saw in a Sample, this way:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
...
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookItemTemplate" >
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>                    
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="25" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PhoneNumbers[0].PhoneNumber, Mode=OneWay}" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="20" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </DataTemplate>
...
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

...

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
    <phone:LongListSelector
        x:Name="AddrBook"
        JumpListStyle="{StaticResource AddrBookJumpListStyle}"
        GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookItemTemplate}"
        LayoutMode="List"
        IsGroupingEnabled="true"
        HideEmptyGroups ="true"
        SelectionChanged="AddrBook_SelectionChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

And I'm doing the user's search for a specific name this way (using LINQ):

```
contactsList = contactsEnum.Where(m => m.PhoneNumbers.Count() > 0 && (m.DisplayName.Split(' ').ToList().Any(p => p.ToLower().StartsWith(tbxSearch.Text.ToLower())) || (m.PhoneNumbers.Any(y => y.PhoneNumber.StartsWith(tbxSearch.Text))))).ToList();
AddrBook.ItemsSource = contactsList; // With IsGroupingEnabled=false
```

I'm looking for a way to highlight the part of the name that matches with the search, but I can't do this, with the way I made the data binding...

Does anyone know how I could do the highlight?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, whenever the word you type in within the `textbox` matches with the word which could be within the `sub strings` or the `Collection`, you could simply `highlight` it!

```
string[] substrings = regex.Split(Content.Text);
Content.Inlines.Clear();

foreach (var item in substrings)
{
    //if a word from the content matches the search-term
    if (regex.Match(item).Success)
    {
        //create a 'Run' and add it to the TextBlock
        Run run = new Run(item);
        run.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        Content.Inlines.Add(run);
    }
    else //if no match, just add the text again
        Content.Inlines.Add(item);
}
```

References: [Is there a way I can highlight specific text in a textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429699/)

[How to Highlight the result from context sensitive search in windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000521/)